# How can I select text not in a group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select strings that are not in a `$ ... $` group. I can choose the group itself, but it should be the other way around.

Example :

```
$ blah **deneme** blah $ xxx **bold** xxxxx $ blah **bold** blah $
```

First group is `$ blah **deneme** blah  $`

Second group is `$ blah **bold** blah $`

I want to get this in regex `**bold**` so it must start with `**`, end with `**` but cannot be a member of `$...$` group

I wrote regex but what I needed would be to choose the opposite.

```sh
/(?:\$)(.*?)[\*\_]{2}([^\*\_]+)[\*\_]{2}(.*?)(?:\$)/gm
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But I need the entire ** bold ** word, but this should not be in a group that starts with $ and ends with $. The selection in the link I gave is wrong. I don't want the group that starts and ends with $, I just need **bold** that is not in this group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```sh
\*\*\S+?\*\*(?=(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltHumt/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\*\*`: Match starting `**`
- `\S+?`: Match 1 or more characters that are not whitespace (lazy)
- `\*\*`: Match ending `**`
- `(?=(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)`: Lookahead to assert 0 or more pair of `$..$` ahead to make sure we are not matching inside `$...$`

Comment: there is one more thing, it select **** ,i think it's an error. how can i fix that https://regex101.com/r/d61GWI/1

Comment: When I try to change this expression for a single * it also gets the ** starred expression

Comment: I added as many examples as I could to the question and prepared a regex link and I hope I could explain what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help. https://regex101.com/r/hQdXhi/1 @anubhava

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Please forgive me for being new. I did not want to be unfair. I will ask the More part with a new question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your understanding. I will try to provide as much help as possible on your new questions as well.